# Restart Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to restart an anonymous function. If this function had a name I could call it, eg:

```
function myFunction(){
    if(false){
      myFunction();
    } 
}
```

However this situation does not apply to:

```
function(){
    if(false){
        ???  // Perhaps use a "this". Not sure. 
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: So give it a name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution is to just give the anonymous function a name.  But, since you appear to know that, I'll assume that you can't do that.  So, instead, you can just put a named local function inside it and call that:

```
function() {

    function run() {
        if(some condition){
            // call this again in 1 second
            setTimeout(run.bind(this), 1000);
        }
    }

    run.call(this);
}
```

If the value of `this` is not being used in your function, then you can simplify it to this:

```
function() {

    function run() {
        if(some condition){
            // call this again in 1 second
            setTimeout(run, 1000);
        }
    }

    run();
}
```